# Python List/Tuple

Tags: python

Hi i want to modify my list so it shows an (x) at the given coordinate via tuple.

Here is my code so far

```
#w=width
#h=height
#c=coordinates

new_grid = []
def coordinates(w,h,c):
    '''    
    >>> coordinates(2, 4, (0, 1))
    >>> print(new_grid)
    [['(_)', '(x)'], ['(_)','(_)'], ['(_)', '(_)'], ['(_)', '(_)']]
    '''
    b=[]
    for i in range(h):
        new_grid.append(b)
    for  j in range(w):
        c=('(_)')
        b.append(c)
```

i am not sure how to implement (x) at the given coordinates, any help is appreciated
thanks.

Comment: Fix your indentation. Badly indented Python is nonsense.

Comment: fixed sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your approach:

- You declare the global variable `new_grid`, but later you have `grid.append(b)`
- Globals are usually not needed, you could create the grid in the function and update the global using the function's return value
- The two for-loops are separate. Remember that indentation matters in Python
- `b` is declared outside of the loops, and so you append to the same instance all the time
- You overwrite your original coordinate tuple `c` with the string `'(_)'`

Here's a version that I think does what you were originally after:

```
def coordiantes(w,h,c):
    '''    
    >>> print(coordiantes(2, 4, (0, 1)))
    [['(_)', '(x)'], ['(_)','(_)'], ['(_)', '(_)'], ['(_)', '(_)']]
    '''
    grid = []
    for i in range(h):
        b = []
        grid.append(b)
        for j in range(w):
            if (i, j) == c:
               b.append('(x)')
            else:    
               b.append('(_)')

    return grid
```

You could also implement the whole thing as a list comprehension:

```
def coordiantes(w, h, c):
    return [['(x)' if c == (y, x) else '(_)' for x in range(w)]
            for y in range(h)]
```